# reading data from csv file using java and batch inserting using jdbcTemplate

Tags: spring, jdbctemplate

I am getting an exception,

> "Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1"

When I am batch inserting the data read from a csv file. The funny thing is, I get the exception only when I for loop the jt.batchUpdate() method. Otherwise the insert is successful.

Thus my data is in 100s of thousands.. I want to insert it in batches of 5000, but if I dont I get exception.

Code sample:

```
for (int curRowCount = 0; curRowCount < dataCount; curRowCount += batchSize) {
    jt.batchUpdate(insert_query, new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {
    @Override
    public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {
    int rowCount=0;
    try {
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        final String[] data = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
        if(rowCount>0){
        ps.setTimestamp(1, new Timestamp(date.getTime()));
        ps.setString(2, "A"); // so on
        }
        rowCount++;
        }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }}
        @Override
        public int getBatchSize() {
        return dataCount;
        }
        });
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: i am unable to add code sample...due to security reasons..

Comment: What is your SQL statement ? Does it return any values, perhaps an ID of the newly created row ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have fixed English issues with your post and converted lakhs to English.  IT is good that you have uploaded the code.  Please post your sql statement as well, you can change field and table names for security purposes.

Answer (score 0):

The BatchPreparedStatementSetter will be called by Spring as many times as they are elements in the batch.

It will be called the first time with i = 0, and that call *should* fill the PreparedStatement parameters for the insertion of the first row.

Then it will be called the first time with i = 1, and that call *should* fill the PreparedStatement parameters for the insertion of the second row.

Etc. etc. until it reaches the limit: `dataCount`.

But your code doesn't do that. The first time the BatchPreparedStatementSetter is called, it reads all the lines from the reader, sets the parameters for the first row, then replaces them with the parameters for the second row, etc., until the reader has no line anymore. You thus set the parameters for i = 0, with the values in the last line of your file. Then Spring calls the setter instead, for i = 1, but then your reader has been read completely already, so it doesn't set any parameter on the statement, hence the error.

Comment: I have used now the jdbc preparedStatement to acheive my goal, and its working as expected now. Thank you all your responses